# 2SLS with two instruments for one endogenous variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 2sls

I have one endogenous variable and two instruments for it, and I want to calculate my beta with the direct (one step) matrix formula

$\beta_2sls = X' Z(Z'X)^{-1}Z'X^{-1}X'Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'Y$

But if I have two instruments for one endogenous variable X and Z are not the same length.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your 2SLS-estimator is wrong. Check wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variable

Let n be the number of observations. Let Z be the instrument matrix and X be endogenous regressor. You say you have 2 instruments and 1 endogenous regressor, hence Z is n by 2 and X is n by 1.

Projection matrix $Pz(=Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z')$ is n by n, hence the 2SLS-estimator 
$\beta_{2sls} = (X'PzX)^{-1}X'Pzy$
works like a charm. Hence there is probably something wrong with you code/data.

When you get stuck at these things go back to matrix form.